# Is there a way to get numbers out of Google Data Studio and into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have data in Google Data Studio that gets updated from a few sources that don't have historical data. One is a csv of content from our CMS (page, date last updated, etc) that I pull into GDS from Google Cloud Storage, and the other are several Supermetrics Data Studio connectors.

What I'm trying to do is to get the data that is in these GDS reports and automatically pull it into Google Sheets. I've tried making a public report and then using the ImportXML or ImportHTML functions, but that doesn't work. I would love to take those numbers that are pulled into the GDS report, have them display in a cell in Google Sheets, and then use a script to daily add that number to a row in a data sheet, thereby creating a historical set of data from the data in a GDS report.

Has anyone figured out how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently(Apr 2021) there is no automated way to get numbers out of Data Studio into Google Sheets. You can manually export a chart's data by clicking on the chart options and then exporting to Sheets.

If your intention is to automate this, then I suggest revisiting your data flow. Data Studio should be used as a reporting tool and not a data processing one. It should be the last node in your data pipeline. If you need to process and materialize your data in a recurring automated way, that should happen before the data hits Data Studio.